# How to change outer label style on MUI Text Field

Tags: material-ui, label, textfield

I'm using MUI Text field (v5) in my react app and am struggling to change the 'outer' label style (circled below), namely make it bold, larger with a gray background without changing the inner label which should remain regular (not bold) with a white background. (see screengrab below)
I have tried changing various attributes but it alwasy seems to change both outer and inner label

[image: Circled label I want to change]

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look at the applied CSS classes when a TextField is focused, it appears that the proper selector is `.MuiInputLabel-shrink`.  Here is an example using a custom component using `styled`:

```js
const CustomTextField = styled(TextField)<TextFieldProps>(() => ({
  "& .MuiInputLabel-shrink": {
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontSize: "22px",
    background: "#c9c9c9",
  },
}));

[...]

<CustomTextField variant="standard" label="Address 3:"/>
```

[CodeSandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-shrink-label-formatting-j4gljn?file=/src/Demo.tsx)